# crontab is not working via cross-compiling

Tags: linux, cron, cross-compiling, yocto

I'm using iMX6S with Yocto. And my OS does have crontab/cronie. And I didn't build that OS image, so I can't modify it. So I did a cross-compile version of cronie. I get a file executable which name crontab. I check and get:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=3d8a5ebf81249e88a8b93badbabf83c8fc1f2b9d, not stripped
```

I edit it via: $ crontab -e

```
@reboot /home/root/loop
*/2 * * * * /home/root/cvtVid2Img
```

But it's not working. Did I missing something ?

What should I do now?

Comment: add a log file you your `crontab` entry with `..... > /tmp/cvt_log.$(date +\%Y\%m\%d.\%H:\%M) 2>&1` to see what is happening. Good luck.

Comment: Hi shellter, thank you for your reply. I added follow your guide: 
@reboot /home/root/loop > /tmp/cvt_log.$(date +\%Y\%m\%d.\%H:\%M) 2>&1 
After 5 minutes booting, I can't find any file with that format. It seem like crontab isn't start at boot.

Comment: Also check the `mail` for the user that "owns" underwhich you created the `crontab`. ... AND what do you get for `which crontab` and/or `type crontab` ? ... Also see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info .

Comment: This is my result: 

$ which crontab
--> 
/bin/crontab

$ type crontab
--> 
crontab is hashed (/bin/crontab)

Comment: After cross-compiling, I just copy executable file and run it. So I guess I'm missing something, but actually I don't know what is it.

Comment: if you `ls -l /bin/crontab` does the date/time-stamp on the file indicate that it was created by your cross-compile? Did you run your crosscompile (and install) as `root`? If not, look at the dir where you ran the cross-compile and see if it contains a `crontab` (using `ls -l crontab` again). Maybe you'll need to cp/mv that version to `/bin`. Good luck (going to bed now).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I built a OS image and compare. It's work now.

Comment: Is there a way to make this more useful to other readers in the future? If you can explain your research and solution as an answer below it would be more helpful to others. And you can accept your own answer (after 48? hrs) and I'll upvote it, so you gain reputation points here. Glad you solved your immediate problem. Good luck.

Comment: 1) You would need to make clear if `cronie` is something different or just a slang for `cron` or `crontab` (if a slang, better to drop it). 2) I would change *"I don't build"* to **"I didn't build"** .3) Include the actual command you used for *"I check and get"* (not just the output).  4) Include output of `ls -l` commands mentioned above.  5) include output of `ls -l /usr/cron/*`. (All In My Humbel Opinion (IHMO) ;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: Actually, cronie is a package which replaces for crontab in Yocto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all help. This is how I solved my problem:
1. I built an OS image with crontab package. 
2. Search all relevant packages with crontab.
3. Copy it to my old OS image.
Hope this help.